# Query syntax with php variables to select from two MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a family tree database. I get the data to display by doing:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM persons WHERE ref='$personID'";
```

This works nicely. However, I've recently added another table called `census_data`. I'm trying to query this table at the same time as the persons table without success. I've tried doing this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM persons, census_data 
WHERE persons.$personID = census_data.$personID ";
```

The error I get says:

> Unknown column 'persons.405' in 'where clause'.

I'm far from competent with databases, but this error seems to be talking about columns, while it is a row that I'm looking for. Obviously I've messed up.

How do I do this?

Comment: This looks [terrifyingly insecure](http://bobby-tables.com/). Are you **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join persons and census_data and also limit data by the personID:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM persons, census_data 
WHERE persons.ref = '$personID' AND persons.ref = census_data.person_id_column_name";
```

The way you have it the query is looking for a column name equal to your personId (405 in your example) instead of looking for a personId of 405.

Comment: Works great! Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: Learn explicit join syntax it will help you avoid such errors. Tip. Dont use commas between tables. `from persons inner join census_data on`